# Is there a SIMD equivalent for the bt instruction in x86_64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, simd, avx2

With the `bt` instruction, I can get the value of the n-th bit in a byte in one instruction. When converting that operation to SIMD, I currently put the source bytes, indices and a `0x1` constant into separate registers and use `vpsravd` followed by `andps` to do `(byte >> index) & 0x1` in every lane. Is there an instruction that could do that quicker for me?

An example for context: This is for indexing into a bitset, i.e. something like (pseudocode)

```
count = 0
for index in indices:
    count += (bitset[index >> 3] >> (index & 7)) & 1
```

Comment: Which SIMD instruction set extensions do you wish to use?  But yeah, using `vpsravd` followed by `vpand` (not `andps` please) is probably one of the better choices.  AVX-512BW has `vptestmb` which might be slightly more useful.

Comment: You might be able to just use the SIMD equivalent of byte & indexn where you have 8 pre-computed constants indexn = 0x1 << index, then consider the results as zero or non-zero. If you insist on the non zero result being 1 then I think you need two instructions.

Comment: `vpsllvd` (with an inverted count) can shift the bit you care about to the *top* of an element, where it can be the control operand for `vblendvps` or whatever.  Or where `vpsrad y, y, 31` can broadcast it to all bits.  Or where you can extract them into a bitmap with `vmovmskps`.

Comment: Is `index` known at compile time, or known to be in some range? Or do you iterate through several `index` values in a loop? And do you actually need the result in the lowest bit? Maybe show some more complete example application.

Comment: @chtz I added an example. The index is not known at compile time.

Comment: What is the size of `bitset`/the range of `index`? And what SIMD instruction set can you use (SSE2/AVX2/AVX512...)?

Comment: Also, if there were no duplicates in `indices`, could you store it as a bitset as well? Then the problem would simplify to the bitcount of the bit-and of both sets.

Comment: @chtz AVX2. The bitset is 2^24 bits = 2^16 bytes and the index has the same range. The indices are not unique.

Comment: I guess a `vpgatherdd` and a `vpsrlvd` together with some masking is essentially the best solution then (you should work on 32bit level and not on byte-level for the shifting, of course). Btw: 2^24 bits = 2^21 bytes ^^

Comment: Are duplicate indices rare?  If you have a lot of indices (enough to make a dense-ish bitmap for chtz's popcnt(a&b) idea) but few repeats, you could construct a bitmap out of the unique ones, with an extra array of just the duplicates.  (Or index, count pairs).  But constructing it would be no faster, and isn't read-only so it's even harder to parallelize (like `bts`).  So that's only useful if you use the same set of indices repeatedly.

Comment: 2^24 bits is not 2^16 bytes by the way, that's 2^21 bytes (or maybe there were 2^19 bits?)